# Why does piping a string with literal quotes to xargs make them disappear?

Tags: shell, unix, xargs

I am writing bash scripts which contains chained `printf` pipeline. (imaging constructing JSON objects)

My usage is something like this:
`printf \"abc\" | xargs printf`
The result is `abc` without quotes. What I need to do if I want to preserve the quotes in the second printf output?

Comment: Note that this is one of the reasons using `xargs` without either `-0` or `-d` is a generally bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This is `xargs` behaving as-documented; it implements shell-like (but not strictly shell-compatible) parsing and quote removal.

Both GNU and BSD platforms have extensions beyond the POSIX baseline that let you disable this.

On systems with *either* GNU or BSD extensions, use `-0` and delimit your input with NULs:

```
printf '%s\0' \"abc\" | xargs -0 printf
```

With GNU xargs, you can use `-d` to specify a delimiter to use -- a context in which a newline is valid:

```
printf '%s\n' \"abc\" | xargs -d $'\n' printf
```